# Reading data from file and put into NSString

Tags: iphone

NSData *finaldata2 =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DefaultProfilePhoto.jpg"]];

now when i convert this NSData to NSString at that time i'm getting value null.
How to resolve this problem

I need data of my png file into 1 NSString

Comment: First check that the file exists and is readable.

Comment: You're talking about a png file, but are loading a jpg file. Also, what text do you expect in the NSString at the end? A png or jpg contains image data, not text.

Comment: I need jpg and I need it's content in NSString but it is right now in 
NSData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every subclass of `NSObject` has a [`-description`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBAFEH) method, including `NSData`:

```
NSString *finaldata2String = [finaldata2 description];
```

For `NSData` this will create an `NSString` representation of the data, making a [string of bytes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/description) in hexadecimal format.